# How to comment on a example of a topic

Tags: support, documentation

So I was going through a topic, and I thought a particular example of that topic is written in a way that it will be very hard for the beginners to understand(it was beginner topic). Now If I am to change it, I would have to change almost all of it OR I can change the title and move some stuff.

So, I thought commenting on that example to discuss it with other contributers would be perfect for this situation. Is there is any way to do this?

Comment: Your only real option is to flag it as "needing improvement". Or downvote and pick one of the reasons, this has the exact same effect as far as I can tell.

Comment: Requested topics have a comment feature, I don't see why we shouldn't have the same for improvement requests too.

Comment: A comment section for only the contributors would be nice

Comment: This system seems inconsistent with how comments work in SO Q&A.  I know that Documentation will be different, but the way it is now seems different from everything ever.  I was hoping for a Talk page or something, like on a wiki.